# problems with group by function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm having a little problem.  I'm trying to get a date into my table, but an error occurs when trying running it. 
I have googlet the error end tried som solutions, but none of them worked. Before adding the date to the Select clause, it worked fine.

```
Select Postal_Code, Sum(Letters), To_Char(trunc(Start_time),'DD-MM-YYYY') AS StartTime
    from Table_name    
    Group by Postal_Code
```

As you can see, im trying to select the date. I dont know how to make it work. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group by Postal_code per day:

```
Select Postal_Code, Sum(Letters), To_Char(Start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS StartTime
from Table_name    
Group by Postal_Code, To_Char(Start_time,'DD-MM-YYYY')
```